# Email send not clickable url after registration PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, email, url, clickable

my problem is in the email sent after users registration. While you get an email for your account verification there is a link you need to visit with your browser to verify your account.

This link is **not clickable**, you have to copy and paste it into your browser. **But I need to make it clickable.** I found the source of the link in my php files.

**Source code of the link in the email verification**

```
'.get_bloginfo('url').'/?ekey='.$emailhash;
```

The whole source is

```
                $body = _d('Hello',17).' '.$yourname.'<br /><br />
'._d('Before you can use the site you will need to validate your email address.',795).'
'._d('If you don\'t validate your email in the next 3 days your account will be deleted.',960).'<br /><br />
'._d('Please validate your email address by clicking the link bellow',1025).': </br>
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . '/?ekey=' . $emailhash; ?>">some link</a>

                escort_email("", "", $youremail, _d('Email validation link',1026)." ".get_option("email_sitename"), $body);
```

Is there any way to make it clickable as the a href tag or something like that?

Thank you.

Comment: is the link not in the accepted format with the full `http://` and `href`? The question is rather short on detail and code.

Comment: *"Is there any way to make it clickable as the a href tag or something like that?"* - This is HTML 101 stuff.

Comment: http://websiteurl.xx/?ekey=c3b1a85849230d36c10edf8a4f9fd161

The link looks like this in the email after you register, the problem is that its not clickable, you need to copy and paste it.

Comment: Remove the "disabled". If its not there, its not a link (<a>)

Comment: as I said in my comments.  Here http://www.hyperlinkcode.com/make-hyperlink.php

Comment: It must be complete url in anchor tag.

Comment: I already have tried to make it with <a> but it doesnt send email then

Comment: you've been given an answer below; ask them. Looks promising

Comment: Didnt work with that code, white screen after registration and no email received

Comment: white screen most likely means syntax errors and you need to find out what it is. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - also, if you're trying to send mail as HTML, then you will need to use the proper headers for it. See the manual on that http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php that's if you're using PHP's `mail()` function, however the syntax is standard when sending as HTML with any mailing method.

Comment: given what you posted and I had to edit, contains syntax errors and looks to be some type of plugin.

Comment: How is it possible that with the original code it works and with the modified code i am stuck at the white screen?

Comment: error is here `<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo` you're already in PHP so you have to get right of the PHP tags/echo. There may be more errors but that one stood out like a sore thumb *lol* and a missing closing quote and  semi-colon.

Comment: Can you please take a look and fix it, i am not that skilled in php I just need to make it clickable thats all.

Comment: Well can you transform the code please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML anchors look like this

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">some link</a>
```

You are going to need to concatenate on the link that you want to display which is..

```
get_bloginfo('url') . '/?ekey=' . $emailhash
```

so that it replaces the "example.com link above.

You can do it like this...

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . '/?ekey=' . $emailhash; ?>">some link</a>
```

**EDIT: Try this code:**

In response to the opies updated code... your anchor tag was already being echoed out inside of php tags so a solution like this:

```
<?php    
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . '/?ekey=' . $emailhash; ?>">some link</a>
?>
```

is going to fail because we can't have nested `<?php ?>` tags.

The solution is to simply **concatenate** the values that you want into the echoed html like this:

```
$body = _d('Hello', 17) . ' ' . $yourname . '
<br />
<br />
' . _d('Before you can use the site you will need to validate your email address.',795) . '
' . _d('If you don\'t validate your email in the next 3 days your account will be deleted.',960).'<br /><br />
' . _d('Please validate your email address by clicking the link bellow',1025). ':
</br>
<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/?ekey=' . $emailhash . '">some link</a>';

escort_email("", "", $youremail, _d('Email validation link',1026)." ".get_option("email_sitename"), $body);
```

Comment: not my downvote and I've no idea why it was downvoted. This seems to do the trick?

Comment: now they retracted it. No idea why they did in the first place.

Comment: slip of the trackpad?

Comment: this code has nothing to do with the business logic of sending your emails, if you are not getting emails then there is something wrong with the business logic and would be best to ask a new question with an accurate title.

Comment: When its set to the original code as I have posted before it works, now with your code I am stack at the white screen and nothing happens

Comment: could you post the code in an edit to your question so that we can take a closer look?

Comment: Done, you can check it out

Comment: sure I see the problem, will update the answer in a moment.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst `echo get_bloginfo` that echo will throw an error. and the `; ?>`

Comment: Still white screen

Comment: @Fred major apologies.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst No need to apologize.

Comment: The modified code is still at the white screen, any other ideas? :/

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst However Jethro and this for the OP to know this as well as future visitors to the question would be to explain why the guy's code failed in the first place about already being in PHP etc. that way everybody knows/learns ;-) a "Try this" type of answer doesn't give specifics. You're doing a bang up job though ;-)

Comment: @LuboEM You're welcome. Glad to have been of "some" help ;-)

Comment: Hey! Glad it works! Well done for sticking with it, in the future you are going to need to learn how to enable error reporting to make this whole process much faster to debug.

Comment: Guys can you please take a look on my next question? 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149985/set-redirection-after-submit-button-is-pressed-help-stuck-at-the-blank-page-p) Thank you :)